# Print out each iteration of Romberg's Method in matlab

Tags: matlab, printf, numerical-integration

so I have code for the romberg method within matlab, I am attempting to get it to output its results for each iteration of q.

What I have tried is displaying as a table, so doing

```
z = [q;iter]
fprintf('%.6f %5d', z)
```

This doesn't produce anything like the correct results, if I include just

```
fprintf('%5d', iter)
```

inside the while loop it will display `1   2` but not the final loop and obviously doesn't tell me my value of Q at each iteration as I haven't included that but at least I felt I was getting somewhere with the iterations coming out nearly how I desire

This is my code with what produces the final iteration and value at the end correctly but not the previous iterations, obviously it won't display older values of q as it is outside the while loop but when I include it within it I get strange results and nothing like what I expect

```
function [q,ea,iter]=romberg(func,a,b,es,maxit,varargin)
% romberg: Romberg integration quadrature
%   q = romberg(func,a,b,es,maxit,p1,p2,...):
%         Romberg integration.
% input:
%   func = name of function to be integrated
%   a, b = integration limits
%   es = desired relative error (default = 0.000001%)
%   maxit = maximum allowable iterations (default = 30)
%   pl,p2,... = additional parameters used by func
% output:
%   q = integral estimate
%   ea = approximate relative error (%)
%   iter = number of iterations
if nargin<3,error('at least 3 input arguments required'),end
if nargin<4||isempty(es), es=0.000001;end
if nargin<5||isempty(maxit), maxit=50;end
n = 1;
I(1,1) = trap(func,a,b,n,varargin{:});
iter = 0;
while iter<maxit
  iter = iter+1;
  n = 2^iter;
  I(iter+1,1) = trap(func,a,b,n,varargin{:});
  for k = 2:iter+1
    j = 2+iter-k;
    I(j,k) = (4^(k-1)*I(j+1,k-1)-I(j,k-1))/(4^(k-1)-1);
  end
  ea = abs((I(1,iter+1)-I(2,iter))/I(1,iter+1))*100;
  if ea<=es, break; end

end
q = I(1,iter+1);
fprintf('%.6f %5d', q, iter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output on the screen you can simply type the variable name without the semi-column character `;` like that:

```
[q, iter]  %q and iter must meet dimensional constraint or

% this will print on the screen the content of the two variables

%for formated output use the command format:
format LONG, q
format SHORT, iter
```

But if you are looking to write in a file you have multiple ways:

The simple way using the command `save` :

```
save filename.mat q iter
```

The more complex is by using `fopen` `fprintf` commands :

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%.6f %5d', q, iter);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, using these methods will only give me the results of the final iteration, I was wanting the q value printed out beside each iteration

e.g

1 = 665.3399
2 = 514.3503
3 = 504.2140

for three iterations. Sorry this really doesn't format well as a comment reply

Comment: not only the final values, you can use them inside your loops. you just need to remove the semi-column `;` after the variable name.  If you want to format your output you can use also `sprintf`like that: 
`disp(sprintf('%.6f %3d\t %.6f\n', q, iter, ea))`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was actually able to fix this pretty simply, must've just been staring at the screen too long earlier as it was very simple

```
while iter<maxit
  iter = iter+1;
  n = 2^iter;
  I(iter+1,1) = trap(func,a,b,n,varargin{:});
  for k = 2:iter+1
    j = 2+iter-k;
    I(j,k) = (4^(k-1)*I(j+1,k-1)-I(j,k-1))/(4^(k-1)-1);
  end
  ea = abs((I(1,iter+1)-I(2,iter))/I(1,iter+1))*100;
  q = I(1,iter+1);
  fprintf('%.6f %3d\t %.6f\n', q, iter, ea);
  if ea<=es, break; end
```

In the second and third last line of that section of code before the while loop ends is where I needed to put the q calculation and fprintf statement which is what I thought initially and thought I had tested but obviously had gone wrong somewhere